# Compiler error which I am unable to locate

Tags: c, compiler-errors, switch-statement, do-while

I'm getting an error which I am not able to resolve. I've gone through my code thoroughly with no success. What am I doing wrong? See code below.

Compiler error:

```
In function 'main':
ou1.c:49:1: error: expected 'while' before 'printf'
 printf("End of program!\n");
 ^
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int choice;
float price, sum, SUMusd;
float rate =1;

printf("Your shopping assistant");


do{

printf("1. Set exchange rate in usd (currency rate:%f)\n", rate);
printf("2. Read prices in the foreign currency\n");
printf("3. End\n");
printf("\n");
scanf("%d", &choice);

switch(choice){
case 1:
printf("Give exchange rate: \n");
scanf("%f", &rate);
break;

case 2:

do{

printf("Give price(finsh with < 0)\n");
scanf("%f", &price);

sum =+ price;

}while(price <= 0);

SUMusd = sum*rate;


printf("Sum in foreign currency: %f", sum);
printf("Sum in USD:%f", SUMusd);
break;

default:
printf("Invalid choice\n");
break;
}while(choice != 3);
}
printf("End of program!\n");



  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without proper indentation your code is barely understandable. Please fix this. (And while doing so, you might even find your error)

Comment: @oxodo, it is not our practice here to tag titles `[SOLVED]`.  Instead, if you received an answer that adequately resolved the question for you then accept it, by clicking the check mark symbol next to it.

Comment: StackOverflow encourage you to answer your own questions. You can do it (and remove Solved tag as well).

Comment: maybe `sum =+ price;` was meant to be `sum += price;`. Although `sum` was never initialized

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces of the switch statement need to be closed before the while loop termination.

`printf("Invalid choice\n");
break; 
} 
}while(choice != 3);
printf("End of program!\n");`

Corrected full code sample

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int choice;
float price, sum, SUMusd;
float rate =1;

printf("Your shopping assistant");


do{

printf("1. Set exchange rate in usd (currency rate:%f)\n", rate);
printf("2. Read prices in the foreign currency\n");
printf("3. End\n");
printf("\n");
scanf("%d", &choice);

switch(choice){
case 1:
printf("Give exchange rate: \n");
scanf("%f", &rate);
break;

case 2:

do{

printf("Give price(finsh with < 0)\n");
scanf("%f", &price);

sum =+ price;

}while(price <= 0);

SUMusd = sum*rate;


printf("Sum in foreign currency: %f", sum);
printf("Sum in USD:%f", SUMusd);
break;

default:
printf("Invalid choice\n");
break;
}
}while(choice != 3);

printf("End of program!\n");



  return 0;
}
```