# Wrong output from insertion sort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

I get the wrong output when I execute my program, and I have no clue to what might be causing it.

As you can se below I have an array. However when executing the program I get the output:

```
array[0]=3
array[1]=1
array[2]=1
array[3]=5
array[4]=5
array[5]=8
```

Obviously it's not my expected output which would be {1,3,4,5,7,8}. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define l 6

void isnertionSort(int array[]);

int main(void)
{
  int array[l]={3,4,1,7,5,8};

  for(int i=0; i<l;i++) {
    printf("array[%d]=%d\n", i, array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  isnertionSort(array);

  for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
    printf("array[%d]=%d\n", i, array[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}


void isnertionSort(int array[])
{
  int j,key;
  for(int i =1;i<l;i++){
    key = array[i];

    j = i -1;

    while(j>0 && array[j]>key){
      array[j+1]=array[i];
      j--;//j=j-1                                                                                                  

    }
    array[j+1]= key;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to debug programs (for example [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)).  You should learn how to step through with a debugger, and/or add print statements to identify what's going wrong.  On SO, you should provide some sample input data and the expected and actual outputs (read about how to create an MCVE — [MCVE]).

Comment: It seems that you overwrite elements in the array when shifting. The debugger is a great tool to identify these kind of problems.

Comment: If the question is resolved accept the answer and tighten the question. You have already received similar [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758008/c-compiler-error-which-i-am-unable-to-locate#comment80461712_46758008). See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Note that using a macro `l` (lower-case letter L) is not usually a good idea.  And although you're consistent in the misspelling, `isnertion` is normally spelled `insertion`.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop has two minor bugs.

```
while(j >= 0 && array[j]>key) { /* j> 0 changed to j>=0 */
    array[j+1]=array[j];  /* changed from i to j */
    j--;
}
```

It's fairly straight-forward to debug if you compare your implementation with [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) algorithm. It would also help if you indent your code so that these sort of bugs can be spotted more easily.

Answer (score 1):

For starters neither declaration from the header `<stdlib.h>` is used in the program. So the directive

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

may be removed.

It is much better to use capital letters for #defined names. For example

```
#define N 6
```

It is difficult to distinguish low case letter `l` and `1` for the reader of the code.

You should write a general sorting function instead of a function that can accept arrays with only fixed 6 elements. So the function should be declared with two parameters as for example

```
void isnertionSort( int array[], size_t n );
```

This loop

```
while(j>0 && array[j]>key){
  array[j+1]=array[i];
  j--;//j=j-1                                                                                                  

}
```

1) does not touch the elements of the array with the index equal to 0 and 1 and 2) sets all elements that are greater than key to `key` because `key` and `array[i]` are the same value.

```
array[j+1]=array[i];
           ^^^^^^^^
```

Taking all this into account the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   6

void isnertionSort( int array[], size_t n );

int main(void) 
{
    int array[N] ={ 3, 4, 1, 7, 5, 8 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "array[%zu] = %d\n", i, array[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    isnertionSort( array, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "array[%zu] = %d\n", i, array[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}

void isnertionSort( int array[], size_t n )
{
    for( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = i;
        int value = array[i];

        for ( ; j != 0 && value < array[j-1]; --j ) 
        {
            array[j] = array[j-1];
        }

        if ( j != i ) array[j] = value;         
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
array[0] = 3
array[1] = 4
array[2] = 1
array[3] = 7
array[4] = 5
array[5] = 8

array[0] = 1
array[1] = 3
array[2] = 4
array[3] = 5
array[4] = 7
array[5] = 8
```